# Flutter/Dart PageView - SwipeGestureRecognizer Activated on Initial Page only?

Tags: flutter, dart, swipe-gesture, flutter-pageview

I've got a `PageView.builder` within a `StatelessWidget`. Each page gets a `SwipeGestureRecognizer` which provides a `Navigator.pop(context)` onSwipeDown. But I'd like this gesture to only trigger when the user scrolls back to `initialPage: 0`.  For the rest of the pages I'd like the default scrolling provided by the `PageView.builder`. I've managed to get this nearly working except the presence of the `SwipeGestureRecognizer` seems to disable the normal swipe down default scrolling of the PageViewer on all the other pages. How can I get the swipe down gesture to activate only on the first page?

```
  class StageBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<SpeakContent> speakcrafts;
  StageBuilder(this.speakcrafts);    
  final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: controller,
      itemCount: speakcrafts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, int currentIndex) {
        return createViewItem(speakcrafts[currentIndex], context, currentIndex);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget createViewItem(SpeakContent speakcraft, BuildContext context, int currentIndex) {
  
    return (
        Container(
        child: SwipeGestureRecognizer(some stuff)
        ),
     );
  }
}

onSwipeDown:() {
    if (currentIndex==0)
    Navigator.pop(context);
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did;

```
 child: SwipeGestureRecognizer(

  onSwipeUp: () {

       controller.nextPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.ease);

       },

  onSwipeDown: () {

       (currentIndex == 0)?

       Navigator.pop(context):

       controller.previousPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400), curve: Curves.ease);

  },
```

...)